# Return probability for an individual unit using logistic regression

Tags: r

How do I return the predicted probability for one unit using logistic regression in R? I ran a logistic regression model, and now I would like to test that model by running it on one unit and seeing what the probability of success is for that unit.

Comment: to get the predicted probability for the `i`th response: `predict(fitted_model,type="response")[i]`

Comment: if you need to predict the probability for a new unit, construct a one-row data frame `newdata` containing the values of the predictors and `predict(fitted_model,newdata=newdata,type="response")`.  (A reproducible example would be nice.)

Comment: I do that, and there are a ton of NA's in the data. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: not without a reproducible example!  http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000